# Conectar SIM800L y Chip AT&T a la Red Celular

Tags: c, http, arduino

Deseo realizar la conexión del módulo **SIM800L** a la red celular para poder realizar peticiones HTTP con GET y POST, cuento con un chip AT&T. Pero no puedo realizar la configuración inicial, estos son mis comandos:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","INTERNET"

AT+SAPBR=1,1

AT+SAPBR=2,1

AT+CLTS=1
```

Gracias y Saludos

Comment: Saludos OSM, revisa el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio, también te recomiendo visitar cómo preguntar aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y finalmente una lista de ingredientes de una buena pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Bienvenido/a a SOes :)

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente no estés haciendo bien las conexiones para lograr la comunicación, ¿en qué etapa estás teniendo problemas? Te dejo unos consejos que pueden ayudarte en tu problema.

**1.-Voltaje**
Recuerda que el módulo sim800 opera entre 3.4 y 4.4 volts y consume hasta 2 amperes.

**2.-Hardware**
Revisa las conexiones, si no puedes recibir respuesta alguna puede que sea porque no están correctamente conectados las líneas de TX y RX

**3.-Código**
Hay un sin fin de códigos en internet, pero solo pocos pueden funcionar perfectamente, checa este [ejemplo](https://github.com/proyectoTEOS/SIM800L-con-Arduino).

```
#include <Sim800l.h> //https://github.com/cristiansteib/Sim800l
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const char receiverNumberT[] = "5613494356", messageT[] = "Mensaje desde el modulo SIM800L numero ", optionalMessageT[] = ", by TEOS";
uint16_t countT = 0, messageDelayT = 5000;
String resultSerialT;

Sim800l Sim800l;

void setup() {
  Sim800l.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(messageDelayT);
  char stringMessageT[55];
  countT++;
  resultSerialT = "El mensaje se ha enviado a " + String(receiverNumberT) + " " + String(countT) + " veces.";
  Serial.println(resultSerialT);
  sprintf(stringMessageT, "%s%d%s", messageT, countT, optionalMessageT);
  Sim800l.sendSms(receiverNumberT, stringMessageT);
  memset(stringMessageT, 0, sizeof(stringMessageT));
}
```

**4.-Operador de red**
Algunos chips de compañías solo soportan ciertas generaciones, como 4G, revisa que tu chip soporte la red 2G ya que es con la única que opera el módulo sim800. Saludos